# foreach not working with glob - error: invalid argument

Tags: php, foreach, glob

I am getting an "invalid argument" error with this code. Please help me fix it.

```
$sub1 = "sub1";
$sub2 = "sub2";
$td = "4";
foreach (glob("directory/".$sub1."/".$sub2."*.td".$td) as $filename) { //This is the line throwing the error
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n"; //This is right from php.net manual
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a slash:

```
foreach (glob("directory/".$sub1."/".$sub2."*.td".$td) as $filename)
```

Should be:

```
foreach (glob("directory/".$sub1."/".$sub2."/*.td".$td) as $filename)
```

(If I've got a variable that's storing a directory, I always add the slash on the end - it keeps things consistent, and means I don't need to remember to cat a slash back on when I'm using it.)

Comment: Thanks! It's always something so stupid that I forget... I did add the slash to each of my variables.